# Undefined function error for cursor.toArray() with locally hosted database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, local-database

I am getting the error:

"TypeError: undefined is not a function" ..for toArray() in the code below.

```
// Require mongo db user model
var User = require("./models/user.js"); 

.
.
.

// list of members page ====================================================
// protected page
app.get("/members", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

    // get array list of usernames
    var pttCursor = User.find( { } , { firstname: 1, lastname: 1, _id: 0 } );
    var membersArray = pttCursor.toArray(function(err, docs){});

    res.render("members.ejs", {
        user : req.user, // get user out of session and pass to template
        members : membersArray
    });
});
```

I want the /members page to have access to an array of usernames.

edit: I have also tried "cursor.map()" .. I get the same error

```
// get array list of usernames
var pttCursor = User.find( { } , { firstname: 1, lastname: 1, _id: 0 } );
var membersArray = pttCursor.map(function(pttDoc){
    return pttDoc.firstname + pttDoc.lastname;
});
```

Comment: Mongoose does not support either method. These are only present in the MongoDB shell. Well `.toArray()` exists in the native driver. But mongoose does not have these. By default "mongoose" returns the result as an array already, unless you explicitly ask for a cursor or stream.

Comment: @blakes, would I set it up like this:   `var membersArray = User.find( { } , { firstname: 1, lastname: 1, _id: 0 } );` ??

Comment: I woluld suggest reading the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find` method from model returns `Query` object not `Cursor`.

To execute query, use `.exec()` method on `pttCursor`.

Also all async methods should be handled with callbacks.

```
var pttCursor = User.find( { } , { firstname: 1, lastname: 1, _id: 0 } )
    .exec(function(err, membersArray){
        res.render("members.ejs", {
            user : req.user, // get user out of session and pass to template
            members : membersArray
        });
    });
```